# G++ raise compile errors instead of warnings for narrowing conversions

Tags: c++, g++, narrowing

I want to get compile errors instead of warnings for this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    float a = 1.3f;
    int b = 2.0 * a;

    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

If I compile it with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

I have no errors.

But If I compile the same code with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -Wconversion
```

I got the following warning:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:6:17: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
6 |     int b = 2.0 * a;
```

I'm looking for a way to get **compile errors** instead of **warnings** only for this particular type of warning.

Obs.1: `-Werror` can make all warnings become errors but it is not what I am looking for

Obs.2: I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-Werror=` to treat specific warnings as errors only:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -Werror=conversion
```